# How to get a property name?

Tags: c#, properties

This might seam like a strange question but....

```
public string MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        return "MyProperty";
    }
}
```

How can I replace the return statement go it returns the property name without it being hard coded?

Comment: It does seem like a strange question. What is the intended use?

Comment: presumably for debug so he can print what method an event is occuring in?

Comment: from c#6, you can use **nameof** keyword to obtain the simple (unqualified) string name of a variable, type, or member

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend doing this in general but here we go:

```
return MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.Substring(4);
```

Using an obfuscator can totally screw this up, by the way.

Comment: Well, isn't that what obfuscators are for? :-)

Comment: Johannes: Probably ;) But you don't want them to make your code throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: thanks :) that worked perfectly. Some further explanation on why I need this: I was given an application that uses about 50 keys from a  webconfig file. And my task is to allow the application to work with any number of clients (needing to replicate these 50 keys for each new client). So, I have moved the keys into a separated file and needed to create a class that encapsulates the data access in order to be able to create an array of clients.

Comment: You don't need an obfuscator to potentially screw this up. The JIT might also do it for you by inlining.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .NET, you can also use LINQ to identify this:

```
public static string GetName<T>(Func<T> expr)
{
  var il = expr.Method.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();
  return expr.Target.GetType().Module.ResolveField(BitConverter.ToInt32(il, 2)).Name; 
}
```

I can't claim credit for this solution - this came from [here](http://abdullin.com/journal/2008/12/13/how-to-find-out-variable-or-parameter-name-in-c.html).

Comment: dazzler ;-)
+1 very interesting approach, never heard of this

Answer (score 0):

from C# 6, you can use nameof attribute to print the name of property or method name.

```
switch (e.PropertyName)
{
    case nameof(YourProperty):
    { break; }

    // instead of
    case "YourProperty":
    { break; }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof